# How to access ruby code variables in the output section of logstash conf

Tags: logstash-configuration

I am working to create dynamic logstash buckets based on date formulas. My objective is to be able to dynamically calculate the date of a logstash bucket based on a defined variable in the incoming log file.

For this, I am currently testing with a single .conf file that contains the input, filter (with ruby code) and output section. I am pushing the output to my elasticsearch setup. I have worked out the formulas and tested the same in regular ruby through 'irb' and the formulas are working as expected.

I am lost when it comes to be able to access a variable which is present in the filter section in the output section.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the following syntax in the `output` section to reference the year/month/date:

```
output { 
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
   user => elastic
   password => "bar"
   index => "foo-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I would try the `"%{variable}"` syntax